# Unable to catch ctrl+c when running mpi4py

Tags: python, openmpi, mpi4py

I have been using a code to deal with some data in ~9000 files, since every single process takes some time, I managed to use mpi4py to speed it up. But I cannot make the program catch the ctrl+c signal and save the results already calculated. Here's the code:

```
import os
import sys
from string import atof
import gc
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from StructFunc.Structure_Function import SF_true, SF_fit_params
import scipy.io as sio
import mpi4py
from mpi4py import MPI
import time
import signal



# def handler(signal_num, frame):

#   combine_list = comm.gather(p, root=0)

#   if comm_rank == 0:
#       print combine_list
#       combine_dict = {}
#       for sub_dict in combine_list:
#           for cur_key in sub_dict.keys():
#               combine_dict[cur_key] = sub_dict[cur_key]
#   print combine_dict
#   sio.savemat('./all_S82_DRW_params.mat', combine_dict)
#   print "results before the interrupt has been saved."
#   sys.exit()


# signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)


comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
comm_rank = comm.Get_rank()
comm_size = comm.Get_size()


bad_value = [-1, -99.99, -1]

lc_path = '/Users/zhanghaowen/Desktop/AGN/BroadBand_RM/QSO_S82'

model="DRW"



if comm_rank == 0:

    file_list = os.listdir(lc_path)
    # print file_list
    sys.stderr.write('%d files were to be processed.' %len(file_list))


file_list = comm.bcast(file_list if comm_rank == 0 else None, root=0)
num_files = len(file_list)
# num_files = 6
local_files_offset = np.linspace(0, num_files, comm_size+1).astype('int')
local_files = file_list[local_files_offset[comm_rank] : local_files_offset[comm_rank + 1]]
sys.stderr.write('%d/%d processor gets %d/%d data' %(comm_rank, comm_size, len(local_files), num_files))
cnt = 0

p = {}

for ind, lc in enumerate(local_files):
    # beginning of process
    try:
        print local_files[ind]
        lc_file = open(os.path.join(lc_path, local_files[ind]), 'r')
        lc_data = pd.read_csv(lc_file, header=None, names=['MJD', 'mag', 'err'], usecols=[0, 1, 2], sep=' ')
        lc_file.close()

        #remove the bad values in the data

        lc_data['MJD'] = lc_data['MJD'].replace(to_replace=bad_value[0], value=np.nan)
        lc_data['MJD'] = lc_data['MJD'].replace(to_replace=np.nan, value=np.nanmean(lc_data['MJD']))

        lc_data['mag'] = lc_data['mag'].replace(to_replace=bad_value[1], value=np.nan)
        lc_data['mag'] = lc_data['mag'].replace(to_replace=np.nan, value=np.nanmean(lc_data['mag']))

        lc_data['err'] = lc_data['err'].replace(to_replace=bad_value[2], value=np.nan)
        lc_data['err'] = lc_data['err'].replace(to_replace=np.nan, value=np.nanmean(lc_data['err']))

        MJD = np.array(lc_data['MJD'])
        mag = np.array(lc_data['mag'])
        err = np.array(lc_data['err'])

        SF_params = []

        resamp_tag = 0
        while resamp_tag < 1:
            sim_err = np.array([abs(np.random.normal(0, err[i], size=1)) for i in range(len(err))]).reshape((1, len(err)))[0]

            try:
                p[lc] = SF_fit_params(MJD, mag, sim_err, MCMC_step=100, MCMC_threads=1, model=model)
                cnt += 1
                sys.stderr.write('processor %d has processed %d/%d files \n' %(comm_rank, cnt, len(local_files)))
                print "finished the MCMC for %s \n" %lc
                resamp_tag += 1
            except:
                continue
    # end of process


    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        combine_list = comm.gather(p, root=0)

        if comm_rank == 0:
            print combine_list
            combine_dict = {}
            for sub_dict in combine_list:
                for cur_key in sub_dict.keys():
                    combine_dict[cur_key] = sub_dict[cur_key]
            print combine_dict

        sio.savemat('./all_S82_DRW_params.mat', combine_dict)
        print "save the dict."
        os._exit()



combine_list = comm.gather(p, root=0)

if comm_rank == 0:
    print combine_list
    combine_dict = {}
    for sub_dict in combine_list:
        for cur_key in sub_dict.keys():
            combine_dict[cur_key] = sub_dict[cur_key]
    print combine_dict

    sio.savemat('./all_S82_DRW_params.mat', combine_dict)
```

I have tried two ways to catch the ctrl+c signal, i.e. the handler function I defined but commented and the except KeyboardInterrupt trick. When I run the code using `python all.py` and then type ctrl+c, the script would catch the signal but keeps running after saving the results; while when I use `mpirun -np 2 all.py` and type ctrl+c, the script just stops without saving.

I think the problem under MPI mode may be that only the manager process catched the signal, but why didn't the single process stop in the non-MPI mode after I typed ctrl+c? Do anyone know how to make the worker process catch the signal and do something before terminating?

By the way I'm using openmpi.

Comment: You're probably right about the manager receiving the ctrl-c in mpi mode. It will always go to the process that is connected to the terminal/keyboard, which is probably the manager. Separately, the reason your script continues after catching the interrupt is that you don't tell it not to. After an `except` clause is triggered, execution will normally continue below the `try`/`except` block. If you want to force the program to terminate, you could include `exit()` in the `except` block. In the mpi case, the manager should send a message to the workers telling them to terminate at this point.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But I have tried exit(), sys.exit() and the os._exit() in the except block, and none of them works...

Comment: I'm guessing that the problem is your catch-all `except:` clause in the inner loop (the one with `resamp_tag`). If a user presses ctrl-c in that loop, it will be caught by the inner `except` clause and simply ignored. If that's not the problem, could you make a more minimal example to help people troubleshoot (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? That will also naturally help you narrow down the elements that are interacting and may help you spot the answer.